# What is a "Snail Toss"?

Tags: meaning

What does *snail toss* mean in the following sentences?

> I'll drop this in the snail toss on the way, all right?
>   I was thinking about some hardcore snail toss later.

Comment: I didn't find _snail toss_ in the dictionary; the British, the American, and the Time corpus.

Comment: Something random and meaningless that someone made up on Urban Dictionary (and didn't even get any upvotes for) should not be the basis for questions on this site (or anywhere else for that matter), IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess from the context, that the usage in the first sentence is an idiosyncratic way to refer to a [snail mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snail_mail) [post box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_box).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=snail%20toss&defid=1105896) is the Urban Dictionary entry for *snail toss*. I've got to say, though, that it is a little bit weird.

Comment: I actually got the 2nd context sentence from Urban Dictionary and it didn't make much sense to me either.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.google.com/search?tbs=bks:1&tbo=1&q=%22snail+toss%22&btnG=Search+Books) the google books search for "snail toss":
The only relevant reference is [Annie's garden journal](http://books.google.com/books?id=NAI5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22snail+toss%22&dq=%22snail+toss%22&hl=en&ei=lGhLTbGlHcOB8gaVsZyNDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA), where the snippet allows me to read:

> Then we had the snail toss contest! We wanted to see who could throw them the fartest and make the loudest noise!

Comment: Personally I prefer the hamster toss game.